# Account get log out after editing account information

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, session, cookie

I have a problem with `Magento 1.9.3.` When I log in as a customer and I make changes to my account information, such as name, last name, etc, and I click save I get logged out. Sometimes everything works fine. I noticed that my `frontend` cookie value gets changed after clicking `save`.

Can you help me with this issue?

What should I check?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below method may be its work for you :

Go to **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie management** and set it to the value you need in the correct store view or if you have only one, in the default config.

also please verify with session.gc_maxlifetime in your PHP config. 0 should give you an endless session.

**hope its will work for you**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tested this on localhost, and when i set my cookie domain same as localhost domain i can not even log in... I had to delete in core_config_data cokie domain value. How should i set this value?

Comment: via admin you can do

Comment: Yes, I know, but what should i type there? for example if i set v-host as example.loc i set cookie domain as example.loc and then i can not even log in..